# Proper way to use CanCan+Rolify on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, rolify

I am just wondering what is the proper way to use CanCan+Rolify in the simplest and most effective way.

I was under the impression that if I had an Ability model like below

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
if user.admin?
  can :manage, :all
else
  can :read, :all
end
```

And I have a resource, let`s say, Product that has

```
resourcify
```

declared, that a user that does not have the :admin role, would not be able to Create, Update or Delete such resource...

But it seems that more code is necessary to implement this behaviour, because I tested and a non :admin user IS able to delete and create a Product.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `load_and_authorize_resource` to your Products controller (assuming that you want to make Products CRUDable only by certain roles of users).

Comment: I ran in the same issue this morning, and this helped me a lot.

Comment: I used authorize_resource, cause my controller scaffolding already does that `def set_product` with the `before_action` set up, so no need to load the resource. Thanks!